# How to install an iPhone application in Linux?

Tags: iphone, emulation

I have the build of an iPhone application. As part of testing i want to emulate it on my Ubuntu. How to do this. Googling simply ate my time

Answer (score 9):

> To provide a differing response, I'm running OS X and Xcode on a virtualised (VMware) machine on Linux. CPU is a Core2Quad (Q8800), and it is perfectly fast. I found a prebuilt VM online (I'll leave it to you to find) Xcode/iPhone development works perfectly, as does debugging via USB to the phone itself.
>
> It actually surprised me a lot but I've had no issues at all.- [Starting iPhone app development in Linux? - Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/923930/1148529)

For more answers, I refer you too:

- [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/276907/1148529)

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You can not emulate iOS applications on Linux. You need the XCode and Cocoa libraries, which only exist on OS X. You have three options:

1. Make a Mac OS X Virtual Machine
2. Create a Hackintosh
3. Buy a Mac.

There is no native iOS emulator for Linux, only Mac. Sorry...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a native app you'll need a mac. Instead of that, you can create hybrid apps with ionic, using only HTML5, CSS and JS.

http://ionicframework.com

Answer (score 2):

I believe the current best way is to run OS X in a QEMU+KVM emulator, then you may run the unavoidable proprietary development tools "natively", including the iOS simulators and the application signing / store upload.

You follow the instructions here: https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM/ and voila, macOS is at your fingertips so you can compile your multi-platform code or whatever it is you need to do.

Possibly also worth mentioning that for Open Source projects Travis CI has a pretty comprehensive and free build environment for OSX

It is also important to note that running OSX on non-Apple hardware is not allowed by the Apple EULA, so this will have varying legality depending on your jurisdiction, unless you are running Linux on the Apple hardware itself.

If you are comfortable with the legality in your jurisdiction and setup, this can work well. I have tested that it does work on Ubuntu 18.04LTS